# Two tables are associated through the middle table, how to quickly obtain the data in one table associated with the other table

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, left-join

Now, I have three tables, which are:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, default=short_uuid, db_index=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app_1'


class GroupQuestion(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', related_name='group_questions',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_constraint=False, blank=True, null=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='group_questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 db_constraint=False, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app_1'

     
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app_1'
```

I want to use the known Group object to find the associated Question object and use the order in the GroupQuestion to sort it. How should I use the orm statement.

My current approach is to first search for the associated GroupQuestoin object through Group and use values_list to obtain question_id, further obtain the Queryset of the Question object, and perform deduplication There is another drawback to this approach.

```py
group_obj = models.Group.objects.filter(uid="xxxxx").first()
question_id_list = list(group_obj.group_questions.all().values_list('question_id',flat=True))
question_objs = models.Question.objects.filter(id__in=question_id_list).order_by(
            'group_questions__order').distinct()
```

There is another drawback to this approach.

When I had two groups associated with the same Queston, I got question_objs with duplicate values, and I had to do some processing to remove duplicate data, which was something I didn't expect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZynyY.png)

```py
# When I do the following
group_obj = models.Group.objects.filter(uid="2fad40GQ").first()
question_id_list = list(group_obj.group_questions.all().values_list('question_id',flat=True))
question_objs = models.Question.objects.filter(id__in=question_id_list).order_by(
            'group_questions__order')
question_objs

# Here's what I got
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0LTU.png)

But the result of not using the order_by method is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Fe4.png)

Can you explain the effect of order_by on the result.

Comment: See this for optimal indexing of the table:  [_Many-to-many_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)